# MM_openBrWindow and Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-chrome

I am using MM_openBrWindow function (in Dreamweaver CS5) to open a popup window (Form link from parent website) on Click of a link on a current webpage. When I fill the form and click SEND button the popup window form gets closed in Safari. However the same leaves an instance of the popup window open in Chrome with an extension action.php open and has to be closed manually.

Does anyone know how can I code (parameters in MM_openBrWindow) should I use so as to close this popup window in chrome?

Thank you

Comment: Yeah, you should not rely on popup windows because many people have them disabled by browsers. I would recommend changing to dialog boxes or modals.

Comment: Its an external form from the parent site, so I am just entering a URL for the action as a Click on the link, but it works fine with Safari, wondering why the popup window does not close in chrome, though data is sent accurately if the SEND button on the form is clicked.

Comment: Now disable popups and use your code. Is the site still viable?

Comment: Yes yes, the function working correctly in Safari browser, however in chrome the popup window does not close on its own after the Send button on the popup form window is closed. Any workarounds?